# gsub regex in R - ignore newline symbol

Tags: r, regex, newline, gsub

Here's a reproducible example

```
S0 <- "\n3 4 5"
S1 <- "\n3   5"
```

I want to use `gsub` and the following regex pattern (**outside of R it works** - tested in regex101) to return the digits. This regex should ignore `\` and `n` whether they occur together or not.

```
([^\\n])(\s{1})?
```

*I am not looking for a way to match the digits with a fundamentally different pattern - I'd like to know how to get the above pattern to work in R*. The following do not work for me

```
gsub("([^\\\n])(\\s{1})?", "\\1", S0)
gsub("([^[\\\]n])(\\s{1})?", "\\1", S1)
```

The output should be

```
#S0 - 345
#S1 - 3 5
```

Comment: `gsub("([^\\n])(\\s{1})?", "\\1", S)`? I think you maybe need an extra escape on the `\s`?

Comment: No sorry, i misread. What i posted does not exclude the new line

Comment: How about `gsub("\n([^\n])(\\s{1})?", "\\1", S)`? I think R requires some extra matching for the regex capture groups to work properly

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding but why not simply `gsub("\n", "", S)`? I also tried `gsub("\\n", "", S)` and both return `[1] "3 4 5"`.

Comment: `gsub("\n([^\n])(\\s{1})?", "\\1", S)` returns `34 5` for me

Comment: @RuiBarradas 2 reasons - first, I'd like to know why it works outside R but not in R - second, the string provided is an *example* and not entirely representative of all of the strings I am processing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you specifically want that regex to work you could match and optional `\n` (using `(\n)?`):

```
gsub("(\n)?([^\\n])(\\s{1})", "\\2", S0)
#[1] "345"
gsub("(\n)?([^\\n])(\\s{1})", "\\2", S1)
#[1] "3 5"
```

Note that you were right, if you use a regex tester like: https://regex101.com/ it works without the extra `"(\n)?"`. However, I think in R you have to match more for capture groups to work properly.

Comment: Thanks Mike H for both the answer and explanation - it works with `S1` as well!

Comment: @CPak, you can also make the first group non-capturing with `?:` so then you would use `\\1`. I think it's technically more efficient, but up to you.

Comment: @CPak This answer is not actually answering the question, it is not necessary to use any additional groups. The patterns used in regex101 and R are different patterns and are handled with different regex libraries.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew is there a better way to do it in R? I'm not very familiar with the specifics of different regex libraries

Comment: @MikeH. Read [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50050969/3832970), you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

Your `([^\\n])(\s{1})?` pattern in regex101 (PCRE) matches different strings than the same pattern used in `gsub` without `perl=TRUE` (that is, when it is handled by the TRE regex library). They would work the same if you used `perl=TRUE` and use `gsub("([^\\\\n])(\\s{1})?", "\\1", S1, perl=TRUE)`.

**What is so peculair with the [PCRE Regex `([^\\n])(\s{1})`](https://regex101.com/r/iqoTto/1)**?

This pattern in a regex tester with PCRE option matches:

- `([^\\n])` - any char other than `\` and `n` (put into Group 1)
- `(\s{1})?` - matches and captures into Group 2 any single whitespace char, optionally, 1 or 0 times.

Note this pattern does not match any non-newline char with the first capturing group, it would match any non-newline if it were `[^\n]`.

Now, the same regex with `gsub` will be

```
gsub("([^\n])(\\s{1})?", "\\1", S1)               # OR
gsub("([^\\\\n])(\\s{1})?", "\\1", S1, perl=TRUE)
```

**Why different number of backslashes?** Because the first regex is handled with TRE regex library and in these patterns, inside *bracket expressions*, no regex escapes are parsed as such, the `\` and `n` are treated as 2 separate chars. In a PCRE pattern, the one with `perl=TRUE`, the `[...]` are called *character classes* and inside them, you can define regex escapes, and thus the `\` regex escape char should be doubled (that is, inside the R string literal it should be quadrupled as you need a `\` to escape `\` for the R engine to "see" a backslash).

Actually, if you want to match a newline, you just need to use `\n` in the regex pattern, you may either use `"\n"` or `"\\n"` as both TRE and PCRE regex engines parse LF and a `\n` regex escape as a newline char matching pattern. These four are equivalent:

```
gsub("\n([^\n])(\\s{1})?", "\\1", S1)
gsub("\\n([^\n])(\\s{1})?", "\\1", S1)
gsub("\n([^\\\\n])(\\s{1})?", "\\1", S1, perl=TRUE)
gsub("\\n([^\\\\n])(\\s{1})?", "\\1", S1, perl=TRUE)
```

If the `\n` must be optional, just add `?` quantifier after it, no need wrapping it with a group:

```
gsub("\n?([^\n])(\\s{1})?", "\\1", S1)
        ^
```

And simplifying it further:

```
gsub("\n?([^\n])\\s?", "\\1", S1)
```

And also, if by `[^\n]` you want to match any char but a newline, just use `.` with `(?n)` inline modifier:

```
gsub("(?n)(.)(\\s{1})?", "\\1", S1)
```

See [R demo online](https://ideone.com/X8aPdh).

Comment: I was waiting for your answer - but I'm unable to get `gsub("([^\\\\n])(\\s{1})?", "\\1", S1, perl=TRUE)` to work for me. Here's the output `"\n3 5"` - it's only when you add the anchoring `\n?` in front does the pattern work for me - which is essentially what Mike H described

Comment: @CPak Good, you just need to understand the difference between what you paste in regex101 and the string literal you use in `gsub`.

Comment: Thanks Wiktor - as always your posts are very instructive

Answer (score 0):

A couple of issues. The is not a backslash in your S object (it's an escape-operator rather than a character) and there is a predefined digit character class that can be negated:

```
gsub("[^[:digit:]]", "", S)
[1] "345"
```

If in the other hand you wanted to exclude the newline character and the spaces, it would be done by removing one of the escape operators, since they are not needed except for the small group of special characters that exist in the character class context:

```
gsub("[\n ]", "", S)
[1] "345"
```

Comment: Hi @42-, thanks for the response - nice to see you here - I'm updating my post to better illustrate why I want the pattern that I want and not another pattern

Comment: Your question remains unclear because the treatment of spaces is not well described. In one case you remove the spaces and another you preserve some of them.

Comment: I'm not trying to be difficult, but I disagree - my title and post do not mention that the objective is to *remove certain spaces* - rather to get the regex pattern that works outside of R to work in R.

Comment: You are saying that you want to remove "\" or "n" whether or not they occur together, but then you offer two examples where neither of them occur.

Comment: The `[^\n]` pattern, which in R is `[^\\\\n]`, is what I was referring to when I said I want to ignore the newline characters - it doesn't remove them *per se* but it will ignore them when capturing groups - sorry if I misled with my wording.